# copy files tool with limiter?

Tags: file-transfer

For testing I need a tool that can copy files from location a to b.

However, I need to tell the tool how many files it should copy per second.

Does any one know a tool that can do this?

Comment: Do you need really a limit of files per second, or simply a limit in the "bandwidth" of copying? Because if you have different sizes of files, limiting the number of files per second is not really reliable, I think.

Comment: In this case it's really the number that i'm interested in. the files have all the same size. it's just for testing something.

Answer (score 2):

file copying speed will be related with [Data Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) that is a region of memory used to temporarily hold data while it is being moved from one place to another. [WinMend](http://www.winmend.com/file-copy/) can handle buffer size you want to perform file copying task. 
If you want and command line apps, try  [Fast Copy](http://www.ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en) . You can use `/bufsize=N(MB)` to Specify the size(MB) of the main buffer for Read/Write operation.

for more choice, you can even check [here](http://www.techmalaya.com/2008/06/11/windows-file-copy-faster-speed/).

Answer (score 0):

[TeraCopy](http://codesector.com/teracopy) is your best bet.

You will know how fast something copying. How many files per second is not a good metric as file sizes change.

[image: TeraCopy File Progress]

[image: TeraCopy Progress]